# Unable to load an ipython magic extension sparkmagic: module not found

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am new to loading custom `magics` into `ipython`.  The instructions to load the

> sparkmagics

extension include the following steps that have been completed successfully:

```
pip install sparkmagic
pip show sparkmagic
jupyter-kernelspec install sparkmagic/kernels/sparkkernel
jupyter-kernelspec install sparkmagic/kernels/pysparkkernel
jupyter-kernelspec install sparkmagic/kernels/pyspark3kernel
jupyter-kernelspec install sparkmagic/kernels/sparkrkernel
```

The command `pip show sparkmagic` Seems to be healthy:

```
$pip show sparkmagic
Name: sparkmagic
Version: 0.10.1
Summary: SparkMagic: Spark execution via Livy
Home-page: https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/sparkmagic
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: mock, requests, tornado, nose, notebook, ipywidgets, ipykernel, pandas, hdijupyterutils, autovizwidget, ipython, numpy
```

Something that did *not* work - but listed as optional is ;

```
$ jupyter serverextension enable --py sparkmagic

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-serverextension", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/serverextensions.py", line 300, in start
    super(ServerExtensionApp, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 256, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/serverextensions.py", line 217, in start
    self.toggle_server_extension_python(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/serverextensions.py", line 206, in toggle_server_extension_python
    m, server_exts = _get_server_extension_metadata(package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/serverextensions.py", line 334, in _get_server_extension_metadata
    m = import_item(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sparkmagic'
```

The error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sparkmagic'` seems ominous. Given the `show sparkmagic` were healthy then why the complaint here? **What is missing still to make the *sparkmagic* module correctly set up ?**

In any case I also tried inside `ipython` and predictably it failed:

```
%load_ext sparkmagic.magics
```

Here is the first portion of the (very long) stacktrace. Let me know if the entire trace were required.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2b579b518c56> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'load_ext sparkmagic.magics')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2161         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2162         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2163         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2164
   2165     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2082                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2083             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2084                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2085             return result
   2086

<decorator-gen-64> in load_ext(self, module_str)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194
    195         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.pyc in load_ext(self, module_str)
     64         if not module_str:
     65             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 66         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     67
     68         if res == 'already loaded':
```

In summary it is likely there were a step typically required for installing/using *any* magics.  Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in your error and install messages, you installed spark magic for python2.7 and are trying to run it in python 3.6. Its confusing and when I started, I too had the same issue many many times. I would suggest that you check which version of python you are using by running     `!python --version` on the notebook. If its the correct version of python, then install sparkmagic using `!pip install sparkmagic` and check the install messages if its installing to the correct version of python.

You could also set up an environment, makes life much more easier. More here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjQlmee58hg

Comment: Looks like `jupyter` is picking up `3.6`: `ipython` and `python` are going to `2.7.x`.  Let me sort that out and get back. I'm upvoting for starters here.

Comment: ok so yea it's `jupyter` causing the issue : first line is `#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6` . That's  a problem: we work in `2.7`: will look  into what to do.

Comment: I needed to `pip install --force-reinstall jupyter` to get this all cleaned up.

Comment: Are you fine to work with both 2.7 and 3.6? On my machine I have 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 installed together. All what I do is start an environment for each Python type. Watch the video, it seriously will help and make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had this problem in Ubuntu. The problem was that the system did not know where `magic` was.

it was in my site-packages, inside my conda environment, so this is what I had to do:

```
jupyter-kernelspec install `dirname \`which python\``/../lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparkmagic/kernels/pysparkkernel --user
```

You first need to `conda activate` your environment so that `which python` points to the right location.